# using session variable in aspx page in sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the sqldatasource in aspx page and in the query I want to use one parameter i.e. coming from session.

Below is my  code.Please help me out.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="MySQLData2"
ConnectionString='<%$ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>'
ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tablename  WHERE id="Here I want to use session variable"" />
```

Comment: Please edit your question title!!! does it really mean anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="MySQLData2"
    ConnectionString='<%$ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>'
    ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tablename  WHERE id=@SessionVar">
  <SelectParameters>
     <asp:SessionParameter Name="SessionVar" SessionField="SessionVariableName" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Are you sure, this will work? How does the data source associate @SessionVar with the SessionParameter?

Comment: Should `SessionVar` and `SessionVariableName` be different?

Comment: I think it should be `Name="SessionVar" SessionField="SessionVariableName"` or you just use `?` like mreyeros pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter.sessionfield.aspx) article should get you what you need.  Basically you would define your SelectCommand with the parameter placeholder, "?", and then define your SelectParameters collection with an entry for your SessionParameter.

Answer (score 0):

Using parameters is rather simple:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource id="Employees" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Northwind%>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT LastName FROM Employees WHERE Title = @Title">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="Title" 
      ControlID="DropDownList1"
      PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

Just replace the value of parameter with your variable:

```
 <%= Sessiom[variable_name] %>
```

Comment: Thanks John..But this is not working as it is giving me runtime exception that you have problem in query.My query is right as it is running fine when I am running it replacing a constant value with session variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=LAZY-PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [C] WHERE ([C#] = @column1)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="column1" SessionField="id" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Johnny_D's answer is pretty much spot on, but I'd like to point out that there's a [`SessionParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter.aspx) class that you can use for this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="MySQLData2"
    ConnectionString='<%$ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>'
    ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id= ?" />
      <SelectParameters>
          <asp:SessionParameter
            Name="id"
            SessionField="SessionVariableName"
            DefaultValue="0" />
      </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```